# how to block web application based on date in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have developed one web application for my client in asp.net. That application has been hosted in the web server. If my client does not satisfy my requirement, I want to block that web application running from the server based on date. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can ether use the `Application_BeginRequest` to make that test as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
   string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cTheFile);
   // here you can check what file you wish to cut, ether by file, ether by extention
   if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
   {
     // and here is the time limit.
     if(DateTime.UtcNow > MaxDateToUse)
     {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        return ;    
    }    
  }
}
```

ether add the same test inside a BasePage use that BasePage for all pages, and make there that test as I describe it on this answer: [Make an asp .net web app offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064360/make-an-asp-net-web-app-offline/13064591#13064591)

relative:
[Making a web site available only for a specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870829/making-a-web-site-available-only-for-a-specified-time/9870918#9870918)
[switch off the all functions in .net service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777762/switch-off-the-all-functions-in-net-service/12777952#12777952)
[Make an asp .net web app offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064360/make-an-asp-net-web-app-offline/13064591#13064591)